# Can't lock nft after delegating using metaplex

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, metaplex, nft

According to metaplex docs here : https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/delegates, I first use the approve function to select a delegated authority. The function works as expected and here I can see that https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2rc14gbRE11jT6uJrpf6SzL2wBcFaaaetjXEJPQMMZLJB6dWqkoXYMAbrp5sh3KKkYRqKu1Gcr7ET67yG1o1SSUz?cluster=devnet, delegate authority is now of my choice account with publickey : 5nsp1dfFFxoneGKEhSgaUvFiHDFtTqSBc3bUBqTedh8r

When I connect to my d'app using the delegated authority wallet(5nsp1dfFFxoneGKEhSgaUvFiHDFtTqSBc3bUBqTedh8r) and try to execute the lock function, I get an incorrect account error. But as I mentioned above I can see that the delegated authority is correct in Solana Explorer.

What am I missing here ?

Here is the code for delegateAuthority :

```
await delegateStandardV1(umi, {
   mint,
   tokenOwner: wallet.publicKey,
   authority: wallet.publicKey,
   delegate: standardDelegate, 
   tokenStandard: TokenStandard.NonFungible,
 }).sendAndConfirm(umi)
```

Here is the code for lock :

```
 await lockV1(umi, {
   mint,
   authority:wallet.publicKey,
   tokenStandard: TokenStandard.NonFungible,
 }).sendAndConfirm(umi)
```

To be more precise, I connect with the d'app using the owner wallet of the nft and set it's delegate to the second wallet which works just fine.

Then I connect to the d'app with the second wallet and try to execute the lock function and I get "incorrect account" error.
I can do other things with the delegation such as transfer the asset to another wallet but lock doesn't work.

Any answer would be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using to Lock?

Comment: I just added the code blocks. They are taken directly from the metaplex docs.